# What happened when I clear the interrupt flag before entering the interrupt handler?

Tags: arm, stm32, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Let say an interrupt (interrupt 1) happens while I am in an ISR for another interrupt (interrupt 2) with the same or higher priority. Then before exiting the current ISR, I clear the interrupt flag of interrupt 1. Will the interrupt handler of interrupt 1 still be executed or interrupt 1 will be ignored?

For context, I am using STM32 microcontroller.

Thank you

Comment: When you read the (arm as well as st) documentation what did you find?  What part did you not understand?

Comment: STM32 is too vague.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: As written the answer to the question is "it depends"

Comment: you need to clear the pending bit in the NVIC controller as well. clearing those bits will skip the another interrupt

Comment: The ARM does not have an interrupt controller itself, so you should at least refer the interrupt controller that the STM uses.  Ie, NVIC xxx?  The fact you have not reported this is the question shows little research.  In some cases, controller may nest.  Ie, a SPI interrupt controller may be a particular NVIC source.  By using the SPI controller, you can mask/alter individual SPI sources, but not by NVIC directly.  This topology is lacking ("It depends").

Comment: @artlessnoise of course it has NVIC **is** a part of the core and it is present in **ANY** Cortex M uC https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0337/e/nested-vectored-interrupt-controller/about-the-nvic

Comment: In the use case you are describing , I think interrupt 1 goes to "pending" state. So even if you clear the interrupt flag (I assume you mean the flag in the peripheral ?) I think interrupt1 should still be served. note that if interrupt1 has higher priority it will be served immediatly when it goes to pending state (nested interrupt) so actually the use case you are describing can only happen if both interrupts have the same priority

Comment: "of course it has NVIC is a part of the core and it is present in ANY Cortex M uC" Technically the NVIC is a peripheral of the Cortex M cores, like the MPU or the FPU. In practice, knowing whether it is a peripheral of a part of the core is not very interesting for a software developper...

Answer (score -2):

AFAIK from the past experience of other CPUs, you loose the interrupt.

In such a case before clearing the interrupt 1 flag:

- simply read the interrupt 1 flag bit and store it temporarily
- clear the interrupt flag (in some CPUs reading it, clears it automatically)
- at the end of the interrupt 2 check the stored bit

  - if it is not set, just leave interrupt 2 routine
  - if it is set and both interrupts have same priority (or it does not matter!):

    - just jump/call the other interrupt 1 routine ("stay" in interrupt 2 routine execution)
  - if it is set and interrupt 1 has not the same priority and you really have to assign it the proper one:

    - then it gets difficult, here some options:

      - once I forced the cpu to trigger an other unused interrupt 3 of the same priority like interrupt 1, so using interrupt 3 to execute "interrupt 1" routine
      - build the interrupt priority handling in code as far as you need it and can, using above trick and more...

PS: This should be described in the manual of the processor, whether clearing the interrupt bit will loose its execution - mostly yes, the interrupt bit is simply a "interrupt pending" bit. It's sometimes not easy to find the description, but daily business.

Comment: needed to DV as the answer does not have anything in common with STM32. I would suggest to read some documentation before answering the question

Comment: It is the duty of cuckoo to read the documentation, he did not, otherwise he would know the answer or add more details of his investigation before questionning. Therefore I added a "PS" as hint.